# Opening biosemi bdf data using MNE and biosig using python

Tags: python

I have a biosemi bdf of EEG data which contains 32 channel. 
I've opened it using biosig, everything works great, a first list is channel and inside each list there are eeg data.
But if I open it using MNE it the first list is eeg data, and the second list (inside the list of eeg data) are two list of eeg data.

this is how I open the data using MNE

```
raw_file=read_raw_edf("E:\eegDATA\\256\s02_reduced.bdf",preload=True,verbose=True)
```

Am I missing something here?